# Replacing a command in a string with its output

Tags: sh

In Bourne shell I have a string variable *s* which contains the character sequence `foo $(ls) bar` (which is not a string literal). How can I get a string where the `ls` command is replaced by its output?

Comment: What do you mean, "which is not a string literal"? Did you run the command `s='foo $(ls) bar'`?

Comment: @chepner The string variable *s* contains the mentioned character sequence at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `eval`, although this isn't really recommended unless you have complete control over how the value of `s` is set.

```
# Modified slightly for this example
$ s='foo $(echo baz) bar'
$ eval "s=\"$s\""
$ echo "$s"
foo baz bar
```

Comment: Before seeing your answer I tried `eval` but I never thought of evaluating an assignment. Thanks!